# Does Azure Storage cache the overlay result?

Tags: caching, azure, azure-storage

From this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898870/does-the-azure-table-storage-api-cache-results), I realized that Azure storage has cache mechanism built-in.

My question is, for the latter query condition, it is not the same with previous one in the cache, but the result it returns contains some same data with former cached result, does the Azure storage also cache these part data, so it would be faster?

### Query 1:

Got result: `[a, b, c, d]`

### Query 2:

Got result: `[b, c, d, e]`

Was the `b, c, d` in *Query 2* retrieved from azure storage cached memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities may not be cached. In addition, Table is designed to provide best result for entity lookups i.e. key lookup, rather than any kind of scans.